# Custom generic DTO Assembler

Tags: c#, generics, dto, activator, data-transfer-objects

I'm trying to create a method which can be used like this:

```cs
Assembler.CreateTransfer(i);
```

- `i` is an item inside a `dynamic` collection.
- `i` is a domain object.
- `CreateTransfer()` should return an instance of `i` type + Transfer (if my domain object is `User`, then it should return an instance of `UserTransfer`.

As for my models is like this:

```cs
public abstract class UserBase {
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class UserTransfer : UserBase, ITransferObject { }

public partial class User : UserTransfer, IModelBase, IDomainObject {
    public User() {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

So far, I've accomplished this:

```cs
public static TTransfer CreateTransfer<TTransfer, TDomain>(TDomain d)
        where TTransfer : ITransferObject
        where TDomain : IDomainObject
    { ... }
```

- This works, because I know the type of `TTransfer` and `TDomain`.
- And I can call it like: `CreateTransfer<UserTransfer, User>(d)`.

The problem comes when I try create the dto without specifying any type:

```cs
CreateTransfer(d);
```

Of course I've added an overload for this task and I hope I can *magically* accomplish the following:

```cs
public static ITransferObject CreateTransfer(IDomainObject d) {
    // do magic
    return CreateTransfer<transfer, domain>(d);
}
```

But in the real world, this is as far as I could get:

```cs
public static ITransferObject CreateTransfer(IDomainObject d) {
    var dType = d.GetType();

    var assemblyName = dType.Assembly.FullName;

    var domainName = dType.FullName;
    var transferName = domainName + "Transfer";

    var domain = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, domainName).UnWrap();
    var transfer = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, transferName).UnWrap();

    return CreateTransfer< ?, ?>(d); // Problem
}
```

- Both `domain` and `transfer` objects are being created correctly.

The main question is: **Is there any way to be able to call `CreateTransfer<domain, transfer>(d)`?** Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to call the generic method.

Something like this:

```
var method = typeof(ClassThatDefinesCreateTransfer)
                 .GetMethods()
                 .Single(x => x.Name == "CreateTransfer" &&
                             x.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
                 .MakeGenericMethod(dType, transferType);
return (ITransferObject )method.Invoke(null, new object[] { d });
```

You probably want to cache at least the result of `typeof(ClassThatDefinesCreateTransfer).GetMethods()`.

Comment: +1 Thank you Daniel, but unfortunately this didn't work, it throws an exception complaining about an ambiguity. Temporarily I'm calling actively the `CreateTransfer<TTransfer, TDomain>(domainObject)`.

Comment: @Esteban: The problem is that you have two methods with the same name and number of parameters in the same class. Please see update, it should fix that problem